# How to specify redirectUrl after logout for Ambassador OAuth2 Filter with Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, ambassador

I'm using the Ambassador OAuth2 Filter to perform OAuth2 authorization against Keycloak.
For the logout I use the the RP-initiated logout as described in the [Docs of Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/topics/using/filters/oauth2/)
The logout works fine. However I could not figure out how to provide the redirect url needed for Keycloak to redirect to the Login page after successfully logged out. As a result the user stays on the blank logout page of keycloak.

The RP-initiated logout looks as follows

```
 const form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = 'post';
    form.action = '/.ambassador/oauth2/logout?realm='+realm;
    const xsrfInput = document.createElement('input');
    xsrfInput.type = 'hidden';
    xsrfInput.name = '_xsrf';
    xsrfInput.value = getCookie("ambassador_xsrf."+realm);
    form.appendChild(xsrfInput);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
```

I expected that Ambassador provides a way to add the redirect url as a query param or something, but I couldn't find a solution.
Are there any suggestions or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the Ambassador documentation that could be overlooked as I did several times:

[Ambassador OAuth2 Settings](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/topics/using/filters/oauth2/#oauth-client-settings)

> **protectedOrigins**: (You determine these, and must register them with your identity provider) Identifies hostnames that can appropriately set cookies for the application. Only the scheme (https://) and authority (example.com:1234) parts are used; the path part of the URL is ignored.
>
> You will need to register each origin in protectedOrigins as an authorized callback endpoint with your identity provider. The URL will look like **{{ORIGIN}}/.ambassador/oauth2/redirection-endpoint**.

So it looks like ambassador hard codes the redirection-endpoint (redirect_uri) that you need add to your OAuth2 client in Keycloak.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i'm not sure if this is what i am looking for. When executing the post as described above, Ambassador redirect the browser to the logout URL of keycloak. The URL Ambassador redirects to looks as follows:  `http://auth-serve}/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout ` . But for redirecting to the application after logout, keycloak expects the query param redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri. Hence I need  Ambassador to redirect to to this URL:  `http://auth-server/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri `  .

Comment: Looks like you handle logout like this - https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/topics/using/filters/oauth2/#rp-initiated-logout - which would suggest you can just add the query param to the realm url for ambassador

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that, is not the best solution but you will logout using a button.

```
async function logout() {
const data = new URLSearchParams("realm=keycloak-oauth2-filter.ambassador")
data.append('_xsrf', getCookie("ambassador_xsrf.keycloak-oauth2-filter.ambassador"));
fetch('/.ambassador/oauth2/logout', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
  .then(function (response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.text()
    } else {
      throw "err";
    }
  })
  .then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

}